Serve as an SMS Provider
Creating an SMS Gateway: Currently, I purchase a certain number of SMS messages from an SMS provider and send them to my customers. Instead of this, I want to become the SMS provider for my customers.
I have no idea where to start! However, I do have my own AWS server for hosting and can create a Spring Boot application if necessary. I just need to know the requirements to become an SMS provider.
I recently started developing an SMS Gateway application using Spring Boot, but now I'm unsure how to proceed. I'm confused about several aspects, such as determining the sender's number when sending an SMS to a customer. I would appreciate a step-by-step guide on how to operate as an SMS provider
